# Time Range with an hour difference

Tags: javascript, date, time, momentjs

```js
   
const all = ['2021-04-26T08:00:00', '2021-04-27T10:00:00',]
const range = ["2021-04-26T00:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-26T01:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-26T02:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-26T03:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-26T04:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-26T05:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-26T06:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-26T07:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-26T08:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-27T00:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-27T01:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-27T02:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-27T03:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-27T04:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-27T05:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-27T06:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-27T07:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-27T08:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-27T09:00:00.000Z",
"2021-04-27T10:00:00.000Z"
]
 
console.log(all, range)
```

is it possible to loop over a list of date like (all) and get all time range from midnight with moment.js like (range)
 any hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example of achieving this. It simply loops until it finds the matching end timestamp and keeps pushing the ISO strings to the `ranges` array.

```js
const all = ['2021-04-26T08:00:00Z', '2021-04-27T10:00:00Z'];
const end = moment(all[1]);

let current = moment(all[0]).startOf('day');
const ranges = [];

while (!current.isSame(end)) {
  ranges.push(current.toISOString());
  current = current.add(1, 'hour');
}

console.log(ranges);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.29.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes but it docent stop at both time ['2021-04-26T08:00:00Z', '2021-04-27T10:00:00Z'] of the day